# How does one prove that a separating hyper-plane exists for a linearly separable pattern?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, classification, separation

How does one prove that a separating hyper-plane that can be represented as a linear combination of the training samples exists for a linearly separable pattern?

Although, it looks pretty obvious physically, I was interested to know if it could be proved mathematically.

Comment: **Hint**: [Rosenblatt's perceptron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron#Separability_and_convergence). I believe this is also discussed in [ESL](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/), but if there's anything about a proof, it's probably in an exercise.

Comment: Thanks, but I think you are pointing to the Perceptron  convergence proof which would prove that perceptron algorithm terminates at a solution vector. I am looking to prove that a hyperplane can classify a linearly separable pattern regardless of the algorithm used.

Comment: My intent was to give you a hint on where to start looking. For example, if you look in the ESL link on pages 130-135 (book's pagination), you will find a discussion and one proof of this fact. In particular, see (4.50) on page 133.